# How does the NodeInterface and nodeField work in relayjs and what does they mean

Tags: node.js, graphql, relayjs, graphql-js

how does the nodeInterface refetch and do object identification,

and what does the `type` represent and what does the `obj` represent, what is `id` here

and what does instanceof mean

```
const { nodeInterface, nodeField } = nodeDefinitions(
(globalId) => {
    const { type, id } = fromGlobalId(globalId);

    console.log('NodeDefinitions (globalId), id:', id);
    console.log('NodeDefinitions (globalId), type:', type);

    if (type === 'teacher') {
        return teacher.findOne({ _id: id }).exec();
    } else if (type === 'college') {
        return college.findOne({ _id: id }).exec();
    } else if (type === 'student') {
        return student.findOne({ _id: id }).exec();
    }
    return null;
},
(obj) => {
    if( obj instanceof Teacher) {
       return teacherType
     }
      // other types too
    return null;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> nodeDefinitions returns the Node interface that objects can implement, and returns the node root field to include on the query type. To implement this, it takes a function to resolve an ID to an object, and to determine the type of a given object.

In GraphQL, data are represented by a tree, and the nodes of the tree are different types of data.
[image]

nodeInterface, nodeField are used to Serialize and Deserialize nodes. for example: if you want to add a book to the book collection, the new book and its id must be provided. Relay will then convert the book object into a new BookType node and add it into the tree.

I have created a demo on how to upload images using React + Relay + GraphQL.

Github repo: https://github.com/bfwg/relay-gallery

Live demo: http://fanjin.computer

Answer (score 0):

**InstanceOf** in this case is checking the class type of the object with the given passed in globalID. See [instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) on Mozilla.

**Regarding** **nodeInterface** The simple answer, and what finally let me understand it, is that the nodeInterface is how the the app stays in contact with the object.Remember what you are doing with GraphQL when you create your schema. You are creating GraphQL class 'Types'. So nodeInterface, is checking your objects GraphQL Type. If you have no schema then you cant have types. The 'id' property is the idea on an instance of your type, or in this case, an instance of 'teacher', 'college' or 'student' GraphQLObjectType. So in a line, relay is saying, give me the objects type and id and I will keep track of it for you. Let me know if you need further explanation.